# What are Java's native ways of communicating with devices directly?

Tags: java, device-driver, ports, device

What are Java's native ways of communicating with devices or ports such as LPT1, COM1, USB directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

native means unportable, so you have to mess with JNI or [JNA](http://jna.dev.java.net/) if and only if the following libraries doesn't works for you:

- [javacomm](http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/) for serial ports
- [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) for USB

Comment: any other ways of doing that by not using any extended libraries?

Comment: No, it's simply not possible without native libraries.

Answer (score 0):

[RXTX](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/intro.html) is good one for COM and LPT ports. USB is extremely difficult; probably the easiest way is to write your own C+JNI wrapper for native drivers of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in Javax.comm the sun version 2.0 and the latest RXTX versions -- LPT parallel ports are not implemented properly under Win32. Output seems to work okay, but if you try to read from the port it's not possible.